# react select dropdown values interfering with react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are using a react-select dropdown and react-table grid below the dropdown. The issue I'm facing is, when I try to select a value from the dropdown, the cursor is trying the resize the table header when the dropdown values overlap with the table header.

I tried to create a sandbox code to explain the issue better but I found the issue in one of the existing examples here [Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yvpq6lx4j1).

Please see the image below to understand the issue.
[Image showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugPBm.jpg)

When the user clicks at the exact point on UI as shown in the pic above, instead of selecting a value from dropdown, the user ends up resizing the table header.

Is there any way to avoid this issue and ensure that the cursor stays on menu list?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add style={{ zIndex: "-1" }} to your ReactTable component

Comment: I was only focused on changing code related to dropdown box. After your answer, I modified the styles of table header and it solved my problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!